# Using IDA pro 7.2 and android server breakpoints problem

Tags: ida, android, debuggers

i have been trying to use IDA to make a breakpoints on a 4 byte memory address 
to find out what arm op code writes to it . yet it fails to set a breakpoint and gives me this message " Xscale support only 1 byte length hardware breakpoints"

am using it on rooted mobile Samsung galaxy S6 , Armv8 
server connection is fine i can live edit values and functions also set a break point on functions ( 1 byte op code ) it works fine  .

so i guess that either am doing something wrong or debugger is limited . 
please note that am new to arm debugging o just want to find the op code that writes to this address for an android game .

thank you much appreciated .

Comment: Could you share address in memory you're trying to "listen"?

Comment: @ Olvin Roght its a dynamic address each time i open a memory scanner ( like game guardian and scan for it and after i put the break point in IDA i get this error )

Comment: You should check is this address is exactly divisible by 4.